# Copy files from corrupted HD using a powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, xcopy

I am trying to use a script that ignores I/O errors on a HD, to copy whatever is good there into another HD.
I found this script here : `http://81.165.15.172:1983/blog/2013/06/02/ignoring-device-io-errors-during-copy-with-powershell/comment-page-1/`
(https://raw.github.com/DavorJ/PS-ForceCopy/master/Force-Copy.ps1)
that does just that...but i cant get it to work.

I am trying with command :

```
.\Force-Copy.ps1 -SourceFilePath "I:\Downloads\" -DestinationFilePath "H:\Downloads" -MaxRetries 6
```

but it gives me this weird error:

```
F:\SSDU\Desktop\Force-Copy.ps1 : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SourceFilePath'. The "Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -Type Leaf" validation script for the argument with value "I:\Downloads\" did not return true. Determine why the validation script failed and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:34
+ .\Force-Copy.ps1 -SourceFilePath "I:\Downloads\" -DestinationFilePath
"H:\Downlo ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Force-Copy.ps1], ParameterBind
   ingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Force-Copy.ps1
```

Anyone knows how to use this in win-8 64-bit ?
-Thanks

Comment: It works file by file, you can't just use a directory path. See examples in Force-Copy help.

Comment: what do you mean file by file ? cause i tried to put just a specific file at the source and destination and it does the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's not a PowerShell solution, but for getting whatever you can off a dying drive I recommend using Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier. You can download it from the author at:

http://www.roadkil.net/program.php/P29/Unstoppable%20Copier

I have had good success with that one.

Comment: will it ignore I/O errors and just move on to the next file ?

Comment: Nice one :) it does skip them :)
Thank you, i've been on this PC for the whole day, and just managed to copy 100gb lol